# Index vs Extended Statistics

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

In Oracle specifically, and possibly other platforms, what is the difference between Indexes and Extended Statistics?  They seem to be constructed is similar fashion and perform the same function.  There must be some core differences - can anyone provide details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm . . . They seem quite different to me.

An index is a copy of data in one or more columns in a table (perhaps with expressions) structured to speed access or to enforce a unique constraint.  The index can be directly used to return values from these columns (or expressions).

Part of the process of creating and maintaining an index provides statistics about the underlying distributions of values.  The optimizer can take advantage both of the data in the index and the information about distributions.  However, the main purpose of indexes is either to provide an alternative, faster access path or to enforce uniqueness constraints.

Statistics (and extended statistics) describe properties of one or more columns.  These properties are used by the optimizer to choose the best algorithm for running the query.  The most important property is cardinality -- the number of different rows -- although skewness can also be important.

Statistics are not used to directly return values in result sets.  They only affect the optimizer.  Indexes can be used to return values; information gathered in the creation of indexes can also be used by the optimizer to define the best execution plan.